# Can't install ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell xps. I currently have it on my thumb drive but when I go install it gives the following error :
" no root for system is defined."
In the installing page I don't see any root files there. Its just completely blank.
When I click the "change" button (in hope's of maybe creating one) another error pops up namely:
"Sorry, Ubuntu 18.04 has experienced an internal error."
And with it a detailed list of what could be going wrong

I've tried some of the tatics described on this site such as doing the following:
Sudo apt update 
Sudo apt install

But nothing has worked. Any help would be much appreciated.
Update : I'm a new user and can't post images

Comment: tell more : do you want dual boot with windows or erase the disk, perhaps a pic of the screen where the error occurs...

Comment: have a look at this (at 3:07) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FjkYC9JpQ1g

Comment: I've removed windows. When I open gparted I have one partition of size 59.62. This partition doesn't show up on the screen when I go through the installation process though.

Comment: OK... Looks like BIOS is configured with Raid  hard drive. Try to change this

Comment: @DTerp If you have solved your problem, do provide the details and steps you followed in the answer section and mark that answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Bios configured for RAID Disk
You may change it for AHCI